# Под моделью появился невидимый куб, как от нее избавиться?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: скрин куба]

Только что начал изучать unity пока не все понимаю. В MagicaVoxel создал модель ,но почему то под моделью появился невидимый куб который мешает как от неё избавится?

Comment: Звоните охотникам за приведениями. Либо наведите порядок в иерархии объектов на сцене

Answer (score 1):

Это компонент Box Collider, удали его с объекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Красной стрелкой отметил куда нажать